# Solving a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

When I tried to solve the equation below, I got the $4$ errors. Since I am pretty new on *Mathematica*, I don't know what I did wrong.

> > $24x_1+20x_2+16x_3=4$
> >       $20x_1+20x_2+19x_3=36$
> >       $16x_1+19x_2+38x_3=19$

This system is set to solve in Jacobi method after $40$ iterations. Initial approximation is $x_1(0)=0, x_2(0)=0, x_3(0)=0$. I would appreciate it if someone could recommend other methods that I can use for this system!

Comment: Please post your (eventually non working) code

Comment: Rewrite it in matrix form and use `LinearSolve`.

Comment: Not going to work with Jacobi iterations. The inverse diagonal matrix times coeff matrix - diagonal matrix has two singular values larger than 1. So you don't get convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Your system is easily solved with [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html). Note the double equal (`==`), a single equal (`=`) wont work because it denotes assignment in *Mathematica*.

```
Solve[{
  24 x1 + 20 x2 + 16 x3 == 40,
  20 x1 + 20 x2 + 19 x3 == 36,
  16 x1 + 19 x2 + 38 x3 == 19}, 
  {x1, x2, x3}]
```

> ```
> {{x1 -> 57/118, x2 -> 349/177, x3 -> -(122/177)}}
> ```

Comment: The first equation in Solve does not exactly match the OP's equation (40-->4), so the posted result is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

And if you like to use `LinearSolve`

```
eqs={24 x1 +20 x2 + 16 x3 == 4,20 x1 + 20 x2 + 19 x3 == 36,16 x1 + 19 x2 + 38 x3 == 19};
vars = {x1, x2, x3};
mat = CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars];
sol = LinearSolve[mat[[2]], -mat[[1]]]

(* {-(570/59), 2401/177, -(392/177)} *)
```